Unable to capture Cypress console logs in TypeScript for Linux and MacOS
I am executing cypress spec file using code as follow and I want to capture logs generated by cypress in console.
Note: result does contain test data but I explicitly wanted to capture console logs.
consoleLogger.bind({ 'xyz': 'abc' })
const result = await cypress.run({
    spec: '/../test.cy.js',
    project: ProjectConfiguration.projectDir,
})
consoleLogger.unbind()

To capture the log I am using following code.
Note: This code works fine in windows machine.
class ConsoleLogger {
  private originalStdoutWrite: any
  private originalStderrWrite: any
  private logger: any

  constructor(testLogger: any) {
    this.logger = testLogger
    this.originalStdoutWrite = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout)
    this.originalStderrWrite = process.stderr.write.bind(process.stderr)
  }

  public bind(extra: {}) {
    // Override stdout to capture Cypress console logs
    process.stdout.write = (
      chunk: string | Uint8Array,
      ...args: any[]
    ): boolean => {
      const output = chunk.toString().trim()
      if (output) {
        try {
          this.logger.info(output, {
            ...extra,
            source: 'stdout',
          })
        } catch (err) {
          this.logger.error(err)
        }
      }
      return true
    }

    process.stderr.write = (
      chunk: string | Uint8Array,
      ...args: any[]
    ): boolean => {
      const output = chunk.toString().trim()
      if (output) {
        try {
          this.logger.error(output, {
            ...extra,
            source: 'stderr',
          })
        } catch (err) {
          this.logger.error(err)
        }
      }
      return true
    }
  }

  public unbind() {
    process.stdout.write = this.originalStdoutWrite
    process.stderr.write = this.originalStderrWrite
  }
}

export default ConsoleLogger

I am also using winston to write console logs to file. I have configured logger as follow.
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston'
import ProjectConfiguration from '../projectConfiguration'

const { combine, timestamp } = format

const TestLoggerFactory = () => {
  const logger = createLogger({
    format: combine(timestamp(), format.json()),
    transports: [
      new transports.File({
        filename: ProjectConfiguration.getLogFilePath(), // Specify log file location
        options: { flags: 'w' },
      }),
    ],
  })
  return logger
}
export default TestLoggerFactory


The logger code works fine in windows system but not in Linux and MacOs.
In Linux and MacOS logs are printed on console not in file.
In Linux and MacOS errors logs are captured in file. Issue is specific to standard out logs.


This question is similar to: Passing process.stdout.write directly vs through callback gives different output?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't want to find command manually and spawn new process. I want to utilize cypress implementation directly.

With Winston, the piping nevertheless works differently, than you might imagine (capturing from console in order to pipe into file seems absurd to me): https://github.com/winstonjs/winston?tab=readme-ov-file#transports
